# Geometric picture of sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Is there a geometric pictures of protosheaf and etale sheaf?

The protosheaf is defined as $(E,p,X)$ where $X$ is base and $p$ is a local homeomorphism on $S_i$ surjective on to $X$ with $\cup S_i=E$ and $S_i$ open in $E$.

Etale sheaf of abelian group is defined as $(E,p,X)$ as protosheaf along with the stalk $p^{-1}(x)=E_x$ is abelian group and the addition and inverse continuous.

Both of them look very weird. Protosheaf looks like a bundle but it is locally homeomorphic to the base open set locally whereas bundle locally looks like a product. Protosheaf looks like a fully discrete topology on one of the product. What kind of picture should I use to interpret the protosheaf?

I have no idea how to geometrically think Etale sheaf of abelian group or other kind of objects in $Ab$ category. How to interpret Etale sheaf of $Ab$ objects?

Comment: Interpret it just like you would a sheaf of groups on a topological space. The whole idea of Grothendieck topologies is that you can think of them as topológicas spaces.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez OK. I will try to think that way. Thanks.